# Create separate column based on email address, using Excel or SQL

Tags: sql, excel, text-to-column

I have a column in Excel with the following

```
Employee
Mickey D. Mouse mickey@disney.com
```

I want it to look like

```
Employee || Email
Mickey D. Mouse || mickey@disney.com
```

In Excel, if I use Text to Column it looks like this

```
Mickey || D. || Mouse || mickey@disney.com
```

So how can I separate on JUST the email, and leave the name in ONE column?

**Please provide help in either Excel or SQL.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just got the email out with this from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1272-excel-extract-email-address.html

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(AL2,FIND(" ",AL2&" ",FIND("@",AL2))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(AL2))),LEN(AL2))),0)
```

And extracted the name with

```
=IF(J2=0, (LEFT(H2, SUM(LEN(H2)-LEN(J2)))), (LEFT(H2, SUM(LEN(H2)-LEN(J2)-1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, assuming that your complete data is consistent as depicted in your question, you can use below approach.

Assuming that source data is in cell `A1` then formula in cell `C1` would be

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

And then to get the rest in `B1` following can be implemented

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,C1,""))`